# MVC 3: где хранить изменяемую модель?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Дано: модель UserModel, представление UserEdit и функция `AttachedEditUser(User old, User modern)`.
Найти: решение, куда передать объект old, чтобы в пост-запросе заменить его на новый имеющейся функцией?

Comment: Не пойму в чем проблема? При посте вызываем нужный экшн, в котором применяем имеющуюся функцию по изменению юзера и возвращаем нужный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Создать модель представления для объектов и передать ее в пост запрос